# Hyperledger Fabric/Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created business network file using composer but when i tried to deployed to fabric 1.0 ,its giving error because I already running another fabric 1.0 in my machine using docker.

Could you please help me to deploy two fabric network on single machine so i can run my composer applications too,
Thanks
Kamlesh

Comment: Can you add error you are facing? Why do you want to run multiple instance of fabric? Usually we do run fabric and then using composer deploy application on top of it

Answer (score 0):

This is a Fabric question, related to how to run multiple instances of Fabric on the same machine and has nothing to do with Composer.